# Common Lisp: How to make just one method unbound?

Tags: inheritance, methods, common-lisp, dynamic-typing

Suppose I have a few classes

```lisp
(defclass mammal ()
  ())

(defclass cat (mammal)
  ())

(defclass dog (mammal)
  ())
```

with their corresponding methods

```lisp
(defmethod make-sound ((mammal mammal))
  (print "yawn!"))

(defmethod make-sound ((cat cat))
  (print "meow!"))

(defmethod make-sound ((dog dog))
  (print "bark!"))
```

How can I remove the `dog`-specialized method while keeping the remaining `make-sound`s? Something like

```lisp
> (mmakunbound 'make-sound 'dog)
(MAKE-SOUND DOG)
> (setq fido (make-instance 'dog))
#<DOG {100471A153}>
> (make-sound fido)

"bark!"
"bark!"
```

I know that I can use [fmakunbound](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fmakun.htm#fmakunbound) but that makes the entire generic function and its methods unbound; `cons`equently I have to recompile `make-sound` for `mammal`s and `cat`s, which is fine in such a small example but quickly becomes a hassle for more complicated class structures.

From what I understand, `defmethod` adds a method to a generic function, so I imagine there could be an operation to reverse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`remove-method`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_met.htm):

```lisp
(make-sound fido)
"bark!" 
"bark!"

(remove-method #'make-sound (find-method #'make-sound () (list (find-class 'dog))))

(make-sound fido)
"yawn!" 
"yawn!"
```

Comment: To be more precise, I have been occasionally looking for ```remove-method``` since three years or so. Many thanks!